# add button dynamically with database vb 2010

Tags: visual-studio

I'm working on visual basic 2010.I would like to add button everytime I add a data in my database(MySQL).

Any help will greatly appreciated.

Comment: We need more context here...

Answer (score 0):

Make a loop and then write

```
Dim button As New Button

For i=1 to 100  'example for loop
Me.Controls.Add(button)  'example for loop
button.left = 20 + i*10  'example for loop
Next  'example for loop
```

Best Regards

Udar